# Collecting data from various different JFrames efficiently

Tags: java

Consider the following scenario:

I have a JFrame "**Main**" which has a jButton "**caravanDataButton**" which opens another JFrame "**CaravanData**".

**CaravanData** has several JTextFields. Its purpose is to ask the user questions and transfer the answers back to **Main** once the user has completed.

My question: **What is the most efficient way of transferring data from a child JFrame to a calling parent JFrame (Or from this example from CaravanData back to Main)**

Ideally I would like to do the following:

```
class Main
{
    public Main
    {
        CustomVariable data = new CaravanData();
    }
}
```

However, a constructor doesn't have a return type. But this would be the best way because the variable "data" wouldn't be assigned a value until the class **CaravanData** had finished its business.

My alternative solution is to use getters and setters. But I have to wait until the user has completed the form before I retrieve the data. I used a while loop:

```
class Main
{
    public Main
    {
        CaravanData caravanData = new CaravanData();
        while (caravanData.isUserFinished == false) 
        {//...Do nothing}

        // Once the user has finished - collect the data:
        CustomVariable data = caravanData.getRelevantData();
    }
}


class CaravanData
{
    ...
    public boolean isUserFinished() 
    {return ifUserHasCompletedForm;}

    public CustomerVariable getRelevantData()
    {
        ...
        return data;
    }
}
```

I don't think this method is efficient at all. Is there a better technique? I have a few JFrames because there are a lot of question to be asked. I wasn't sure how to word this to find answers on the net. I did think of using threads? Stopping one process until the other finishes. But I was under the impression you only use threads when a task consumes to much time from the EDT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a JDialog as your child Window. The `setVisible(true)` method of JDialog blocks till the dialog is disposed (usually by calling `setVisible(false)` from inside the dialog)

After that you can load all data by your `getRelevantData()` method.

```
 class Main
 {
     public Main
     {
         CaravanData caravanData = new CaravanData();
         // Show the dialog - setVisible(true) blocks till ok is pressed
         caravanData.setVisible(true);

         // Once the user has finished - collect the data:
         CustomVariable data = caravanData.getRelevantData();
     }
 }

class CaravanData extends JDialog
{
    ...
    // Called by an ActionListener for the OK Button
    private void okButtonPressed(){
         setVisible(false);
    }

    public CustomerVariable getRelevantData()
    {
       ...
       return data;
    }
}
```